# Best practice for bundling items in the service container in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to take all my classes that I'm adding into the DI container and put them in their own class.  I don't want to just have a big long startup file.

What I did was added this to my `ConfigureServices` method

`new ServicesConfiguration().SetServices(services);`

Then inside this class I have

```
public class ServicesConfiguration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds dependency injection items to the container
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    public void SetServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Scopes
        services.AddScoped<AuthorizedUser>();

        // Singletons
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        // Transients

    }
}
```

Is this best practice?  I'm passing services as a parameter. Just not sure if that's correct to be able to access it in side my new class.

Comment: I like Autofac's Module system for this. I end up with things like `UserModule` which contains all of the user-related registrations, etc. I imagine you could do something similar with a method (e.g. `RegisterUserServices(IServiceCollection services)`) to logically split up registrations.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. A lot of libraries do extension methods on IServiceCollection, which is another way to do it, but it comes down to preference really.

Comment: Using a class for this is a bit "ugly". You're better off with extension method for `IServiceCollection`, then you call it with `services.AddMyServices()`. THis is how every other library do it, the `AddMvc` or `services.AddRouting()`are nothing else than extension methods on `IServiceCollection` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s fine - it’s just a style thing. Just be careful that you don’t spread out your registration code too much. I’ve seen some codebases where there were tons of extension methods used to configure DI. It made it very difficult to track down where things were getting registered.

Comment: Nothing wrong with extension methods. You can make on extension method per type of service you register (in case you are developing a library). Its the normal and recommended approach doing it